# relaunch an app without quitting in iPhone

Tags: iphone

How can we call a main() method without quitting an app at runtime....or can we relaunch a application without quitting an app.... or can we reload a main window xib file without quitting an app...in iPhone

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238979/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot terminate an app using the iPhone SDK and you can't restart it either.

If you want to get back to your main/initial screen then you just need to pop whatever view controllers you have in your navigation stack and restore the main view to its initial state.

Comment: hello Mike, Thanks for the replying but i am not getting yours answer...I am using exit(0) for terminating my app, is it in HIG or not...Please elaborate yours answer or if possible provide some codes..Basically i need to relocate my app in different languages for that purpose i need to relaunch my app..... Regards,
Manjot Singh
Software Developer.