# how to change the language in ios without restarting the app programmatically?

Tags: ios, xib

My app contain two XIB files for English and Arabic language.I want to change the XIB files when language change without restarting the application.

Comment: i think you need to Detect current iPhone input language then according to that you can use your xib files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change app language programmatically WITHOUT restarting my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786501/how-to-change-app-language-programmatically-without-restarting-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

I have done same kind of task in my recent project Need to support Arabic & English. Where I need to change Language according selected option from list. I have created two .xib  one for Arabic and one for english and then select

// for setting bundle

```
+(void) setContentBundle{

    SS AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSString *currentLanguage;

    if([delegate.strLanguage length]> 0)
    {

        currentLanguage = delegate.strLanguage;

    }else {

        currentLanguage = @"en";

    }
    if ([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"ar"]) {  // If ARABIC.

        languageBundle = nil;

        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ar" ofType:@"lproj"];

        languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

    }else if ([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"en"]){  // If ENGLISH.

        languageBundle = nil;

        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];

        languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

    }
}



// getting localiation key value
+(NSString *)getLocalizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)v table:(NSString *)t{

    if([key isEqualToString:@"FollowUp.DepartmentKey"]){

        NSLog(@"%@",key);

    }
    SSAppDelegate *delegate = (SSAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"KEY LIKE[c] %@",
                             key];


    NSArray *filteredArray = [delegate.arrSystemMessages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


    NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);

    if(filteredArray!=nil && [filteredArray count]>=1){

        NSMutableDictionary *dict=[filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];

        if([[ContentBundleManager selectLanguage] isEqualToString:@"ar"]){

            return [dict valueForKey:@"AR"];

        }else{

            return [dict valueForKey:@"EN"];

        }

    }else{

        return [[ContentBundleManager getContentBundle] localizedStringForKey:key value:v table:t];

    }

}

//for getting bundle


+(NSBundle *) getContentBundle{

    SSAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSString *currentLanguage;

    if([delegate.strLanguage length]> 0)
    {
        currentLanguage = delegate.strLanguage;

    }else {

        currentLanguage = @"en";

    }
    if ([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"ar"]) {  // If ARABIC.

        languageBundle = nil;

        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ar" ofType:@"lproj"];

        languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

    }else if ([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"en"]){  // If ENGLISH.

        languageBundle = nil;

        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];

        languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

    }
    return languageBundle;
}


/// and call .xib
    SSBaseViewController *baseView= [SSLBaseViewController getBaseViewObjectWithBundle:nil];

/// and call string file

    [baseView setHeaderTitle:[ContentBundleManager getLocalizedStringForKey:@"FollowUp.FollowUpKey" value:@"" table:nil]];
```

Comment: How to set  ContentBundleManager in ios?

Comment: content bundle is nothing but idea for fetching xib according selected language. Check +(void) setContentBundle it is doing same thing.

Comment: what you have used FollowUp.DepartmentKey in your project?

Comment: what should i write in ContentBundleManager?